# Не отображаются контролы, ссыляющиеся на шаблоны из MergedDictionaries (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources

Имеется файл разметки для шаблона кнопки:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProj.UI.DesktopClient">
    <!--Шаблон для кнопок-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BlueButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border
                Name="Border"
                Background="#FF2F8FD1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                CornerRadius="4"
                TextBlock.Foreground="White"
                TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Name="StrokeBorder" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1, 1"></Rectangle>                
                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!--При наведении мыши-->
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF0044A6"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <!--При нажатии-->
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF003A63"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Этот файл декларирован в App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyProj.UI.DesktopClient.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProj.UI.DesktopClient"
             StartupUri="Authorize.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
                <!--controltemplates-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ControlTemplates/ButtonTemplate.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

В окне для кнопки прописываю следующий код:

```
<Button Content="Войти в систему" Margin="5" Template="{DynamicResource BlueButton}"/>
```

Всё компилируется без проблем, но реально в окне эта кнопка не видна. В чём может быть проблема? Поломал всю голову.

Comment: Я сделал всё, что у Вас написано в вопросе и у меня отображается голубая кнопка.

Comment: @ixSci, у Вас тоже xaml-файл с шаблоном отделён от самой формы?

Comment: Да, просто добавил его в проект

Comment: Кстати, зачем Вы используете `DynamicResource`? StaticResource достаточно, а плюс от него в том, что если шаблон не находится, то он Вам об этом сообщит

Comment: Так вот он мне и сообщает о том, что ресурс 'BlueButton' не найден.

Comment: Попробуйте создайте новый WPF проект и повторите всё, что у Вас написано по шагам

Comment: Но я не могу понять почему. Мне даже IntelliSense даёт подставить его прямо в разметку окна.

Comment: Очень большой проект, не хотелось бы всё заново писать...

Comment: Так Вы маленький сделайте и потихоньку с ним экспериментируйте, так Вы быстрее сможете найти ошибку.

Comment: Как только я перемещаю весь шаблон в разметку окна, всё сразу начинает работать. Но при помещениия шаблона кнопки в ResourceDictionary отдельного файла, получаю ту же проблему.

Comment: Попробовал добавить весь шаблон в App.xaml - то же самое: не работает.

Comment: Можете выложить минимальный проект, где это воспроизводится?

Comment: Хм. А вы не пробовали подключать ваш ResourceDictionary не в App.Resources, а в Themes/Generic.xaml? (Плюс, если у вас ещё не прописано, включите `ThemeInfoAttribute` в AssemblyInfo.cs.)

Comment: @VladD, скажите, а Themes/Generic.xaml должен каким-то способом генерироваться самой студией?

Comment: @klutch1991: Обычно он генерируется автоматически, если вы создаёте custom control (не user control!). Но вы можете, если хотите, и сами его создать. Точный путь важен, не ошибитесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я всегда использовал `StaticResource`, и никогда никаких проблем не возникало. Попробуйте.

Comment: StaticResource даёт XmlParseException.

Comment: @klutch1991, тогда у вас явно где-то в разметке ошибка, видно, от того и DynamicResource не отображался.

Comment: @klutch1991, посмотрите подробности ошибки, там должна быть информация от чего исключение возникает.

Comment: в Inner Exception указано, что ресурс не найден.

Comment: @klutch1991, я точно не уверен, но что если обернуть ваш шаблон в стиль, просто это единственное отличие от моих словарей ресурсов, у вас голый `ControlTemplate`, а у меня все в `Style`.